# Calling an IF statement | Batch

Tags: batch-file

Error Code:

```
If was unexpected at this time
```

The code sets the stats for each player then it calls the function to determine the amount of damage based on the stats and other variables

What I want to do is call a function with two IF statements within it
Example:

```
@echo off
set /a level=5
set /a opponentLevel=5
set /a movePower=50
set moveType=physical
goto player

:damageCalculator
if %moveType%==physical (
    pause
    set /a damage=(((( 2 * %level% / 5 + 2) * %attackStat% * %movePower% / %opponentDefenceStat%) / 50) + 2)
    set /a opponentHealth-=%damage%
) else if %moveType%==special (
    set /a damage=(((( 2 * %level% / 5 + 2) * %spAttackStat% * %movePower% / %opponentSpDefenceStat%) / 50) + 2)
    set /a opponentHealth-=%damage%
)
goto :eof

:player
set type=fire
set/a health=19
set/a attackStat=10
set/a defenceStat=10
set/a spAttackStat=11
set/a spDefenceStat=10
set/a speedStat=12

:opponent
set /a opponentHealth=18
set /a opponentAttackStat=10
set /a opponentDefenceStat=9
set /a opponentSpAttackStat=8
set /a opponentSpDefenceStat=9
set /a opponentSpeedStat=13

:attack
pause
cls
call :damageCalculator
echo It did %damage% Damage!!
pause>nul
```

Is this just one of those things that batch can't do?

Comment: Change your second `if` to `else if` or add a carriage return before it (after the preceding parenthesis).  Also, move your `goto :EOF` to the next line after the closing parenthesis.

Comment: I know a good way to find out.

Comment: That was it... @rojo

Comment: I wrote it as an answer with a more thorough explanation in case it helps.

Comment: Batch debugging pro tip: If you are confused where an error occurred, REMOVE `@echo off` FROM YOUR BATCH FILE.  YOU ARE SUPPRESSING THE DEBUG INFORMATION.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### update per edited question

Your script has a few small issues.  Firstly, I'll point out that it's often helpful to `rem` out `@echo off` when trying to track down the cause of a problem.  Doing so in this case shows that the line causing your error is your first `set /a` line.

The reason your `if` statements are failing is because the parentheses within your math are being treated as the end of your code block.  As soon as the closing parenthesis of `...5 + 2)` is encountered, the batch interpreter treats that as the end of your `if` statement, and therefore gets confused when there's more stuff on the line.  You need to quote your `set /a` statements to prevent this.

```js
set /a "damage=(((( 2 * level / 5 + 2) * attackStat * movePower / opponentDefenceStat) / 50) + 2)"
```

See how I did `set /a "variable=value"` there?  You could also escape the closing parentheses with a caret -- e.g. `^)`, but quoting the `"var=value"` is a little easier to read I think.  The quotation marks keep the contents within the context of the command.  They're basically saying, "This is a single token.  It's a distinct part of the `set` command, not the code block as a whole."  As a bonus, you can also see that the `%` signs aren't needed to retrieve variable values within a `set /a` command.  Neat, huh?

You've got another problem.  Since you're setting the `%damage%` variable within the same parenthetical code block as you're retrieving it, `%damage%` is going to be evaluated too early.  You could `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and retrieve it as `!damage!`, and that would certainly work.  But there's a simpler fix.  Just put it outside the `if` statements.  You're doing `set /a opponentHealth-=damage` regardless of whether the move type is physical or special, anyway, right?

```js
:damageCalculator
if "%moveType%"=="physical" (
    set /a "damage=(((( 2 * level / 5 + 2) * attackStat * movePower / opponentDefenceStat) / 50) + 2)"
) else if "%moveType%"=="special" (
    set /a "damage=(((( 2 * level / 5 + 2) * spAttackStat * movePower / opponentSpDefenceStat) / 50) + 2)"
)
set /a opponentHealth-=damage
goto :eof
```

But still, you should include `setlocal` just below `@echo off` to keep from junking up your environment with variables that have no meaning outside the scope of this script.

Here's another tip.  You can combine many statements within a single `set /a` line.

Before:

```js
set /a level=5
set /a opponentLevel=5
set /a movePower=50
set "moveType=physical"
```

After:

```js
set /a level=5, opponentLevel=5, movePower=50
set "moveType=physical"
```

---

#### original answer

Change your second `if` to `else if` or add a carriage return before it (after the preceding parenthesis).  Also, move your `goto :EOF` to the next line after the closing parenthesis.

The explanation for this is that the cmd interpreter treats a parenthetical code block as a single command.  So in essense,

```js
if [true condition] (
    action
) second command
```

is being evaluated as

```js
if [true condition] (action) second command
```

which results in an error because there's no line break or other separator between the first command (the `if`) and the second.  Here's an example of a valid compound command:

```js
@echo off & setlocal
```

Compound command need:

- unconditional AND (`&` -- right side always executes after the left)

  - example: `endlocal & goto :EOF`
- logical AND (`&&` -- right side executes only if the preceding command exited zero)

  - example: `find /i "text" "textfile.txt" >NUL && echo Text was found`
- pipe (`|` -- makes the command on the right do something with the output generated by the command on the left)

  - example: `dir /s /b | more`
- logical OR (`||` -- right side executes only if the preceding command exited non-zero)

  - example: `tasklist | find /i "iexplore.exe" >NUL || echo Internet Explorer not running`

... or in the case of an `if` statement, `else`.

```js
if condition 1 (
    action 1
) else if condition 2 (
    action 2
) else (
    action 3
)
```

Or if you want to check that two conditions are true:

```js
if %var% leq 10 if %var% geq 5 (
    echo Variable is between 5 and 10.
)
```

Of course, you don't have to use compound statements.  There's no reason why a function can't have multiple `if` statements that aren't compound.

```js
:fn <str>
if "%~1"=="fish" (echo Bloop.)
if "%~1"=="cats" (echo Meow.)
if "%~1"=="dogs" (echo Grrrr.)
goto :EOF
```

... is perfectly valid.

Comment: That works for my sample code but not the one I'm actually applying it to... I'll edit my question to include the actual one

Comment: @Moonicorn Updated answer.  Hope it helps!